How to Configure a Collection of Value Objects with ToJson Method in EF Core 8 and Npgsql to support soft deletion of the aggregat
I'm trying to configure a collection of value objects in Entity Framework Core 8 using the ToJson method with Npgsql. Here’s the setup:
I have this aggregate
public sealed class Catalog : Aggregate<CatalogId>, ISoftDeletable
{
    public DocumentCollection? DocumentCollection { get; private set; }

    private Catalog()
    {
    }

    public Catalog(CatalogId id, DocumentCollection documentCollection) : base(id)
    {
        DocumentCollection = documentCollection;
    }

    private bool _isDeleted;

    public void Delete() => _isDeleted = true;

    public void Restore() => _isDeleted = false;
}

wrapper to documents (from documentation https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco):
public record DocumentCollection
{
    private DocumentCollection()
    {
    }

    public DocumentCollection(IEnumerable<Document> documents)
    {
        Documents = documents.ToList();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Document> Documents { get; }
}

and document value object:
public record Document(string Name, string Path);

Configuration:
public class CatalogConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Catalog>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Catalog> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("catalog");

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Id).HasConversion(i => i.Value, value => CatalogId.Create(value));

        builder.OwnsOne(c => c.DocumentCollection, dcb =>
        {
            dcb.ToJson("document_collection");

            dcb.OwnsMany(dc => dc.Documents, db =>
            {
                db.Property(n => n.Name);
                db.Property(r => r.Path);
            });
        });

        builder.Property<bool>("_isDeleted").UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field).HasColumnName("is_deleted");
    }
}

Reposiory
public class CatalogRepository : ICatalogRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
    private readonly ILogger<CatalogRepository> _logger;

    public CatalogRepository(
        AppDbContext appDbContext, 
        ILogger<CatalogRepository> logger)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Guid> Remove(Catalog catalog, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _appDbContext.Catalogs.Remove(catalog);

        await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return catalog.Id;
    }

    public async Task<Result<Catalog, Error>> GetById(
        CatalogId catalogId, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var catalog = await _appDbContext.Catalogs
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == catalogId);

        if (catalog is null)
            return Errors.General.NotFound((Guid)catalogId);

        return catalog;
    }
}

Interseptor
public class SoftDeleteInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(
        DbContextEventData eventData, 
        InterceptionResult<int> result, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (eventData.Context == null)
            return await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

        var entries = eventData.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<ISoftDeletable>()
            .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            entry.Entity.Delete();
        }

        return await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
}

use case:
var catalogResult = await _repository.GetById(catalogId, cancellationToken);

// Handle not found error

await _repository.Remove(catalogResult.Value);

When i do this ef core thow an error:
The property 'Document.Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.

Stack trace
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.ThrowIfKeyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IProperty property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ChangeDetector.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase propertyBase, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntryNotifier.PropertyChanged(InternalEntityEntry entry, IPropertyBase property, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetProperty(IPropertyBase propertyBase, Object value, Boolean isMaterialization, Boolean setModified, Boolean isCascadeDelete, CurrentValueType valueType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetStoreGeneratedValue(IProperty property, Object value, Boolean setModified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.WriteJson(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object navigationValue, IUpdateEntry parentEntry, IEntityType entityType, Nullable`1 ordinal, Boolean isCollection, Boolean isTopLevel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.WriteJson(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object navigationValue, IUpdateEntry parentEntry, IEntityType entityType, Nullable`1 ordinal, Boolean isCollection, Boolean isTopLevel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.WriteJson(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object navigationValue, IUpdateEntry parentEntry, IEntityType entityType, Nullable`1 ordinal, Boolean isCollection, Boolean isTopLevel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.<GenerateColumnModifications>g__HandleJson|41_4(List`1 columnModifications, <>c__DisplayClass41_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.GenerateColumnModifications()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.<>c.<get_ColumnModifications>b__33_0(ModificationCommand command)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ModificationCommand.get_ColumnModifications()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.<CreateCommandBatches>d__10.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.<BatchCommands>d__8.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__111.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__115.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__63.MoveNext()

How can I properly configure the collection of value objects to support soft deletion of the aggregate without encountering this error?
